# signing in using curl and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise

I have products controller that renders json.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @products = Product.all
    render json: @products
  end
```

I am using devise for authentication.
My application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


end
```

I want to login using curl
I tried

```
curl http://localhost:3000/products -u "t@t.com:password"
```

its give me response

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Please tell me correct way to implement it.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is:

`curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
   -d "user[email]=user@example.com" \
   -d "user[password]=password" \
 'http://example.com/users/sign_in.json`